# Question about the relationship between subspaces and dimension in vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Hello I'm wanting to answer this question but I cannot figure out really what to do.

Suppose $\overrightarrow{v_1},\overrightarrow{v_2},\overrightarrow{v_3},\overrightarrow{v_4}$ are vectors in a vector space $V$ with dimension $3$, what are the possible dimensions of the subspace given by $U = Span\{\overrightarrow{v_1},\overrightarrow{v_2},\overrightarrow{v_3},\overrightarrow{v_4}\}$ of $V$?

What I have tried so far: Nothing. Can't think of what to do here.

Comment: Well, you have four vectors. Are there any of the possiblities $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ for the dimension of $U$ that you can immediately discard?

Comment: $4$ I believe as with $4$ they would not be linearly independent?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ has always a dimension less than $V$, and dimensions are integers $\{0,1,\ldots\}$.

Comment: So then the answer is 2?

Comment: In a 3-dimensional space, what is the dimension of a line?

Comment: I think it is 1

Comment: In deed because if you take one vector in the line, say $\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$, it forms on its own a linearly independent list because if $\alpha\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar, since $\vec{v}\neq\vec{0}$ therefore $\alpha =0$. The list $(\vec{v})$ also spans this line because any vector $\vec{u}$ on the line can be written as $\vec{u}=\beta\vec{v}$ where $\beta$ is a scalar. Anyway I gave you this example so that you think again about your comment saying that the answer is 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$0,1,2$ or $3$. in the $3$-dimensional vector space, $4$ given vector is linear dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1)  What determines the dimension of a vector space spanned by a set of vectors?  For this question, you can either "stay abstract" and avoid casting them into a coordinate system, or you can draw some insight from a standard physical $3$-space like $(x,y,z)$.

2)  Can a subspace of a vector space have more dimensions than the space itself?

3)  Can it have the same number of dimensions?

4)  Can it have fewer?  What would be the condition(s) on the particular values of the vectors if they did span a subspace with less than three dimensions?

Comment: 1) The number of vectors in the basis of the vector space.
2) No
3) Yes
4)Yes I think so I think that the vectors would need non-zero components.